# Pyserial on Linux With SYMLINK

Tags: symlink, pyserial, udev

I have a python program that uses pyserial to communicate with an arduino UNO through USB. It worked well opening the com port using "dev/ttyUSB#," however, the ttyUSB number often changed when unplugging and replugging in the arduino. To solve this, I decided to create a symbolic link to the arduino device using udev rules. I updated the python code to open the port on "dev/SYMBOLICLINK," and I am now getting an error:

"Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')."

Is there any way I can fix this error while still using the symlink?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't necessarily an answer to the original question, but I figured since there are not yet any answers for this, I would give the workaround I've been using. Rather than creating a SYMLINK for the devices I wanted to reuse, I created a "Devices" object in a *settings.json* file for my project similar to the following:

```
"Devices": {
    "Custom_name_1": {
       "serial_number": ...,
       "pid": ...,
       "vid": ...
   },
    "Custom_name_2": {
       "serial_number": ...,
       "pid": ...,
       "vid": ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Then using the following function:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports
import json


def getDeviceMap():

    ports = list(list_ports.comports())

    with open("./settings.json") as configFile:

        configJSON = json.load(configFile)
        devices = configJSON["Devices"]
        deviceMap = {}
        for port in ports:
            for device in devices:
                deviceData = devices[device]
                if port.serial_number == deviceData['serial_number'] and \
                        port.pid == deviceData['pid'] and \
                        port.vid == deviceData['vid']:
                    deviceMap[device] = port.device
    return deviceMap
```

which returns a dictionary that looks something like:

```
{"Custom_name_1":"COMX", "Custom_name_2":"COMY"}
```

if a device matching the defined parameters is connected, it's pretty simple to open the ports associated with the devices.

Comment: This should not be accepted as an answer as it does not address the issue of resolving symbolic link

Comment: @Fermi-4 Noted. I had posted it as a workaround but you are correct that it doesn't answer my question.